# NODE_LOCAL vs RACK_LOCAL task read time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am studying how locality affects task read time in a spark sql job.

THE TEST:

1. To facilitate the analisys I run a simple SQL query which performs a table scan and returns no data, the task takes time reading the block and then processing it.
2. The Query: "CREATE TABLE target_table AS SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE column_name>1000".
3. Selectivity is equal to 0 (i.e. column_name is never grater tha 1000)
4. Spark context has been created with only one executor so to observe both NODE_LOCAL and RACK_LOCAL tasks.
5. My cluster is composed by 7 nodes equipped with 8 cores each in a single rack linked together with a gigabit swithch (1 gigabit point-to-point)

Before getting to the point of my question I would like to state few hypotheses:

- Each task processes a single block
- As data locality is preferred, the driver allocates NODE_LOCAL tasks first and then RACK_LOCAL ones
- When more than one VCore is allocated, tasks initially compete on the local hard drive to fetch their blocks and then the fetching is done remotely on other nodes
- The network throughput outperform the hard drive throughput therefore under stress hard drive are the bottleneck

Finally the question :)

When many VCores are allocated (e.g. 8) in a single executor, given the hypotheses stated above, I would expect the RACK_LOCAL task's read time to be faster than the NODE_LOCAL's one.

Insted, according to my tests, RACK_LOCAL read time is in average few % points slower than NODE_LOCAL as shown [here](https://forums.databricks.com/storage/attachments/211-taskaverageduration.png). Obviously I am missing something but I digged around without come out with a reason. What is this something?

The linked [figure](https://forums.databricks.com/storage/attachments/211-taskaverageduration.png) shows NODE_LOCAL and RACK_LOCAL average task duration time for increasing numbers of VCores.

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I find out that one of my hypotheses is not correct: *"The network throughput outperform the hard drive throughput therefore under stress hard drive are the bottleneck"*

A gigabit switch performs in average 0.8 its speed, meaning that two nodes are linked together with a network throughput of 100MB/s. HDDs can normally read at 150MB/s.

As remote read and network transfer are performed in pipeline, the small difference between NODE_LOCAL and RACK_LOCAL is due to the remote buffering time which occurs between read and transmit

Answer (score 2):

RACK_LOCAL means that a block is being read from an HDD on a remote node and then is passed over network. NODE_LOCAL means that a block is being read on this node, therefore the "network" part is omitted, therefore NODE_LOCAL in general should be faster.

Comment: That's ok, but when on the node is allocated an executor with 8 VCores, all of them compete on the local HDD in case of NODE_LOCAL increasing the fetching time. On the contrary, 8 VCores retrieving their blocks remotely on different remote HDDs will have to pay the "network" part but should have a great benefit as remote HDDs are much less overloaded.